# What is Stack Exchange's word cloud of sites representative of?

Tags: support, stackexchange.com

I saw the main Stack Exchange site [list of all sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#) has tiles for all of their sites. Is the size of the tiles/speechbubbles representative of the (logarithmic?) quantity of questions for each site or the current activity for each site?

Regardless, very cool feature.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Should I ask this somewhere else?

Comment: The question is absolutely fine here. Perhaps for some the site view defaults to list view and they never saw the "word cloud" you referred to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The larger the speech bubble, the larger the SE site. You can always change from the bubble format to the list format, which is the default when you're logged in.

Comment: I believe the display has not been updated in several years. Stack Overflow in [non-English language] sites are moving up the list quickly by every metric.

Comment: @JonEricson not really, at least not in the grid view. Since the size is hard coded, they aren't going anywhere and will always stay small. (looks like all new sites get the smallest size possible.)